# Dir(fpath) causes an error for inaccessible network location even when error catching

Tags: vba, excel

This might be an unusual question - I certainly can't find anything on it.
Essentially I'm checking whether a location exists using `Dir()`. If the user is on a specific work network, then it is fine, however if they are not then authentication fails (as it should) and the user has no access. `Dir()` causes the sheet to error, even when using error trapping.

Has anyone had this error and know how to get around it?

Comment: Sorry, error is 52. Filepath is something like \\companyname.net\profiles$\username\filename.txt

Comment: Try using the fso: Dim objFSO as Object Dim folderExists as Boolean Dim folderPath as string Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") folderExists = objFSO.FolderExists(folderPath)

Answer (score 1):

I just tried again and for some reason it works now. Either I was an idiot before or the difference is using E.2016. More likely the former. The snippet of the *working* code below.

```
    Dim bErrorState As Boolean

    fPath = fRoot & Environ("USERNAME") & "\OMC_Template_PersonalSettings.txt"

    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo SetErrorState
    bErrorState = Dir(fPath) = ""
SetErrorState:
    If Err <> 0 Then bErrorState = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    If bErrorState Then
        fPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\OMC_Template_PersonalSettings.txt"
        If Dir(fPath) = "" Then Exit Sub
    End If
```

Sorry to waste people's time. Hopefully this will simply be an example of how to catch an error.